# How do I test if mysql timestamp is during the day (between 8:00 and 20:00) with php?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, strtotime

I'm making a page that displays some info in a table and I want that table to have a darker background on the entries from the night time.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
    if ( ($timestamp < strtotime('2012-02-16 20:00:00') && ($timestamp > strtotime('2012-02-16 08:00:00') ){}
```

But I want this to function 24/7 all year. How do I make the date any date (* - * - *) ?

Comment: If your target is global you might wanna get ur hands on a daylight calculator class/database or daylight calendar for any part of the world. This way you can just check the current time of the server and determine how dark ur background should be, if it should have stars etc. Maybe even consult some weather API (this might not be a good idea) and add some clouds too;) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what format `$timestamp` is in, but if it's in Unix timestamp format (epoch seconds), you could do this:

```
$hour = date('H', $timestamp);
if ($hour >= 8 && $hour < 20)
```

If it's not in Unix timestamp format, perhaps you could make it so in your query, using the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function.

Comment: This will limit it to an hour. What if you need minutes too?

Comment: OP asked for between 8 and 20. He didn't ask for minutes.

Comment: `20:00:00`, this time does include minutes, even though they are 0 right now ;)

Comment: *sigh*...splitting hairs here. Think about what he's trying to do. He's trying to determine if something happened during the daytime or night time. In every case that I've ever seen in my life, that lands on an hour. It would strike me as odd if you said that daytime starts at 8:03am for the OP's kind of use. This is a perfectly good and simple solution for the OP's purpose (and probably nearly every other application as well).

Comment: Works great with 1 little change, 19 instead of 20, because if I selected 20, 20:59 would still be considered daytime.
@DainisAbols I don't require minutes.

Comment: Considering your last comment, you do need minutes. Meaning, you need `00` minutes ;)

Comment: @user1675769: Ah, good point. I edited my answer. For clarity, I chose to keep the number `20`, but change it to `$hour < 20` instead of `$hour <= 20`. Same thing as what you did, though. Just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$curtime = date('G', $timestamp);
if ($curtime >= 8 && $curtime <= 20)
{
  //do whatever
}
```

I'd recommend reading up on [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use also can use [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php/) function to make the timestamp.

For example, today, 8PM:

```
$mktime = mktime(20, 0, 0, date(n), date(j), date(Y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can format date with only hours component like

int(date('H', $timestamp ))

and test this value